# AngularJS - To Make Or Not To Make a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that if I want to create a reusable item, such as a date picker, then creating it as a Directive is recommended.

However, let's say that on my homepage, I have a Welcome section that displays the quote of the day with a background image that comes from a Rest service.  Should this be a Directive that can encapsulate the markup and controller logic? Or should it be a simple AngularJs Controller that binds to markup in my index.html?

What constitutes whether or not something should be created as a Directive?

Comment: Its ultimately up to you and how you architect your application. I draw the line on when I require a ui component to be a directive when I use it in more than one place. Once the same thing is duplicated, its more DRY to put that component in a directive.

Comment: Putting the code into a directive also means you can write tests for logic that manipulates the DOM. For example, you have a template that is associated with a controller. In that template you conditionally apply a class or show/hide an element. You cannot test that these things are applied/shown in a controller. But you can with a directive. If your template has lots of logic in it, it could be useful or even important to test that things are working as expected.

Comment: Thanks guys for your valuable input. I haven't done too much with javascript unit tests, so it's definitely a huge plus that directives make it easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Directive is only a wrapper for a controller. It means if you have a controller you can use it. But you also may use the same controller as a controller of a directive for example instead of `link` function use `controller`.

This allow as to draw clear line where to use directive and where to use a controller.

We have to use Controller if we want to reproduce logic of piece of HTML markup. When we want to use the same `$scope` assignments, the same functions inside `$scope`, ... but HTML markup is always different for every other place where we use this controller.

We have to use directive when we have same logic in a controller of a directive and same HTML markup.

So in your case it is definitely a directive.

This is my own common sense of course, and may not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you will require to implement this functionality:

1. AngularJS Template a.k.a. Markup to display quote with an image next to it.
2. AngularJS service to encompass the REST call in order to fetch above details from the server.
3. AngularJS controller to consume the AngularJS service to feed the data back the template (point 1) to update it accordingly after every rest call.

So the fact is you can achieve this without even writing an AngularJS Directive but what if you need to replicate the same feature in many places. In that sense, you will probably have to copy the same template somewhere else which will again need a separate controller to consume the same service (as using the same controller multiple times in the DOM is not recommended and a bad practice).

With the Directive API, you can put the markup in a directive template and consume the service in a directive controller to render the UI. So the next time if you want multiple instance of the widget, you just have to inject the directive, that's it - rest will work without any issue.

```
App = angular.module('App', []);
App.directive('welcomeQuote', function(QuoteService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><img ng-src="{{quote.img}}" /><span ng-bind="quote.title"></span></div>',
    controller: function(scope) {
      // returns {img: 'angular.png', title: 'AngularJS';
      QuoteService.fetch().then(function(data) {
        scope.quote = data;
      });
    }
  }
});
App.factory('QuoteService', function($http) {
  return function() {
    fetch: function() {
      return $http.get('http://quote-server.com/new')
    }
  };
});
```

Finally you can use the widget as:

```
<welecome-quote></welcome-quote>
```